# Couchbase JOIN query always returning empty results

Tags: sql, couchbase

I have been trying to run different kinds of join query on couchbase using the same query as given in couchbase docs but everytime the query results in empty results.

The bucket used is travel-sample which is present in installed couchbase, i have already created index on the docuements.

This is the query i am running on the couchbase console.

```sql
SELECT Count(DISTINCT route.sourceairport) AS DistinctAirports
FROM `travel-sample` airline
    JOIN `travel-sample` route
    ON KEY route.airlineid FOR airline
WHERE route.type = "route"
AND airline.type = "airline"
AND airline.iata = "AA";
```

The logs don't display anything.

Comment: Any idea why the couchbase join query results are always coming blank, i have tried doing on all kinds of JOIN ANSI,LOOKUP and INDEX

Comment: first of all, do make sure the tables you are joining do have entries and any of them fulfils your criterion (that where-and-and). otherwise it might be a [bug on couchbase](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/n1ql-query-stops-working-in-5-5-1-when-keys-has-empty-string-works-in-5-0-1/18408). this question is rather hard to replicate.

Comment: What index(es) have you created for this query?